In my blazor server side app with windows auth., I want to exclude my starting page completely from windows auth. so that no login is required
In my blazor server side app with windows authentication (.NET7 hosted on IIS). So normally when someone visits the page for the first time he has to enter credentials into the standard login dailog of the browser. I want to exclude my starting page (home.razor) completely from windows auth. so that no login is reuired. On the home.razor there will be a intro for my pages and an enter button where the user shall really enter the windows authorized pages. That means after pressing the button the windows login dailog should come.
I have tried to define an exception to the starting page (home.razor) with
  @attribute [AllowAnonymous]

But still the login dialog comes before the start page opens. The reason why I want to do this: When a user enters my page address (in my case an company intranet address with just servername and port) he gets just the login dialog and has no real information about the page. So when his credentials are not accepted he cannot be really sure whether he is on the right page. Because I cannot change the browsers standard login dialog, I wanted to implent such a solution.
